# Prerequisites for Quantum cryptography

Tags: self-learning, cryptography, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Sir i am from mathematics background. I am aware of pure mathematics subjects. My university is offering quantum cryptography in Jan semister. I am an absolute beginner. Can you please list down the prerequisite courses for quantum cryptography?. I have recently joined graduate studies. I want to pursue research in a new area. So this word of "quantum" struck me. When i googled i found another course called quantum computing. Apart from linear algebra, probability(till what extent?), what are other prerequisites? how quantum cryptography differs from normal cryptography course?( i have not done cryptography but i am aware of basic number theory concepts). How quantum cryptography differs from quantum computing? Do i need to have quantum theory background of physics? Is there any connection between this quantum cryptography and blockchain or machine learning please englighten me in layman language. Please tell me possible research areas in this subjects and its interconnection with graph theory, combinatorics, machine learning etc if any Please suggest me some books/resources to get acquantance with the subject?

Comment: The people who are in the best position to advise you on the prerequisites for a quantum cryptography course at your university are the people teaching it. Why not ask them? And, please go easy on the boldface. Too much, and it hurts my eyes.

Comment: I fixed the boldface problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in view of quantum computing, you need functional calculus (incl. tensor products) and complex numbers. This is sufficient at the algorithmic level.

It will depend whether the course will include quantum models for the implementation of the cryptographic protocols in question. Then you would need some quantum mechanics as well.